# Code for selecting multiple items on single drop-down

Tags: drop-down-menu, paypal

Is there a code that you can share for a PayPal button to enable selection of multiple items, and the appropriate pricing of each, from a single drop-down menu? Rather than have multiple buttons taking up real estate on the webpage,it would be cleaner to have a single drop down in each category. also, there would have to be a way for the freight to be calculated based on the items selected.

Note the URL below as a point of reference:

http://earmoldsdirect.net/privacy.html

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with custom code, but you essentially need a developer to program it to your needs.

Alternatively, rather than custom code you can look for a third-party shopping cart that has this type of feature built in to customize an item's options and prices.  PayPal has this partner directory: https://www.paypal.com/us/business/platforms-and-marketplaces/directory

Additionally there are of course very many other shopping cart software options out there that can integrate with PayPal (almost all of them), as any web search will show.